# Postgres: Is it possible to use Point in Time Recovery to rollback to previous states?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to the Postgres Point-in-Time recovery feature and I understand how I can use the WAL to recover up to a certain point in time from a fresh database, but I was wondering if it could be used to go BACKWARDS as well.

```
A -- B -- C 
           \
           Say I'm here and want to drop all the changes between B and C
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL the new [`pg_rewind`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgrewind.html) feature does just this. It's not yet exposed as a general purpose way to do PITR backwards in time, but as far as I know there's no reason that should not become possible later.

At the moment, no, there is no general purpose way to just replay WAL backwards.

You'll want to restore a base backup of `A`, then configure a `recovery.conf` to stop recovery at `B`.

Comment: The link for pg_rewind takes me to a 404. Perhaps the documentation is not yet exposed either?

Comment: Current documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.html